# Getting a foreign key in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my website, a user can add foreignExpressions to his account. The user model looks like this:

```
   [Table("UserProfile")]
   public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public List<ForeignExpression> learnedexpressions { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller I'd like to get the current user's stored expressions like this:

```
db.ForeignExpressions.Select(f => f.UserId == Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);
```

However, ForeignExpression does not contain a UserId field, so there's no visible UserId for f. But the UserProfile has a collecion of ForeignExpressions, so I have a UserId field in the ForeignExpression table. I'm confused, how am I supposed to get the ForeignExpressions for my user?

Edit:

```
    public class ForeignExpression
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string expression { get; set; }
    public string context { get; set; }
    public string meaning { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateAdded { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post what your `ForeignExpression` class?

Comment: Just a suggestion. In order to have a `FK` don't you need in your `UserProfile` something like `public virtual ICollection<ForeignExpression> ForeignExpression{ get; set; }` and in your `ForeignExpression` - `public int UserProfileId { get; set; } and public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int userID = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

db.UserProfiles.Find(q => q.UserID == userID).LearnedExpressions.ToList();
```